# $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}}$ two different procedures with different limits, why is one correct(if it is) and the other not

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

this is my 3rd question of the day but so far you guys have been helping me a  lot, so I hope it isn't too much to ask about 1 more, so i have this limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}}$$

and i've calculated(I am not allowed to use L'hospital's) as follows
$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln((-\cos(x)+1)+1)}{-\cos(x)+1}\frac{(-\cos(x)+1)}{\cosh(x)-1}\to\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{-\cos(x)+1}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{\ln(-\cos(x)+1)}{-2\ln(2)-1}}}\to\frac{\ln(0)}{-2\ln(2)-1}\to\frac{\infty}{-2\ln(2)-1}\to\infty$$
by using $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x_n+1)}{x_n}=1$ and the definition of the $\cosh(x)$ function

and then I tried this way after knowing the limit was 1
$$\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{2-\cos(x)}{\exp(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}-1)}\to_{\lim_{x\to0}}\frac{1}{1}$$

I would like to understand why is the first method incorrect or even if the second one is also correct, where can I see that the logic "falls off"?

As always thank you very much in advance

Comment: Well, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\cos(x)+1}{\cosh(x) - 1} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(-\cos(x)+1)}{-2 \ln(2) - 1} = \infty \text{,}$$ so I would suspect that step of error.

Comment: I don't understand, wouldn't $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\cos(x)+1}{\cosh(x)-1}\to\frac{-\cos(0)+1}{\cosh(0)-1}=\frac{0}{0}$?

Comment: $0/0$ is undefined.  So, no.

Comment: You started off correctly but then something got messed up. Your first approach should show that the limit in question equals the limit of ratio $(1-\cos x) /(\cosh x-1)$ and that is $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain why would$(1-\cos x) /(\cosh x-1)\to1$? we haven't seen any limit identity with $\cosh(x)$

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is wrong because
$$\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{2-\cos(x)}{\exp\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}-1\right)}$$
is wrong. Are you trying to use the incorrect property $e^{a/b}=e^a/e^b$?

As for the first one, the line
$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln((-\cos(x)+1)+1)}{-\cos(x)+1}\frac{(-\cos(x)+1)}{\cosh(x)-1}\to\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{-\cos(x)+1}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{\ln(-\cos(x)+1)}{-2\ln(2)-1}}}$$
doesn't make sense to me. First, a limit doesn't approach another limit. A limit, if it exists, is a number and a limit can equal another limit. So that arrow shouldn't be there. Next, I can't even tell how the second limit became equal to what you wrote.

Here's how this method can work:
$$\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{\ln(1+(1-\cos(x))}{1-\cos(x)}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\cosh(x)-1} $$
Then compute each of the limits separately
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+(1-\cos(x))}{1-\cos(x)}\qquad\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\qquad\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\cosh(x)-1} $$
to find the required limit
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(2-\cos(x))}{\cosh(x)-1}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+(1-\cos(x))}{1-\cos(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\cosh(x)-1}\\&=L_1\cdot L_2\cdot L_3\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh okay thank you  very much for answering! I see where i went wrong in the first method, I tried to do it again and i've realized that it does not equal that, on the other hand though, I don't get why $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\cosh(x)-1}\to2$, as far as I know we haven't seen that limit in class so I am having difficulties to understand why